# Java FileWriter() vs createNewFile()?

Tags: java, api, java-7, filewriter

is there an advantage to using the FileWriter() class & constructor instead of the createNewFile() method in the File class?

I can't figure out the difference or the advantage. createNewFile() seems simpler and more intuitive so I'm thinking of abandoning my use of the FileWriter but I wanted to check.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[File.createNewFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) creates only an empty file.  A `FileWriter` additionally allows you to write character-based data out to a file.

Use the most direct and obvious method available.  If you want an empty new file, the former will work fine.  Anything more complicated will usually involve a `Writer` or `OutputStream` of some kind.

Comment: Does it have to be concerted? In other words, I want to create a new file, but eventually in the same program, I want to write to it.

Comment: You can open / close files as many times as you like, but there is a (generally small) cost to doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to create an empty file, then use [`File.createNewFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29). If you need to write to a file, use [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html). The constructor [`FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) has `append` boolean parameter which is useful in most cases.

However, I recommend to use [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) rather than using [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) to write char-based data to a file, because of its useful methods such as [`println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28%29).

Comment: You should usually make sure to specify a `Charset` when you're working with `Writer`s.  Relying on the system charset to always be set correctly is almost always more trouble than its worth.

Comment: @StevenSchlansker +1 agreed!

Comment: The disadvantage to this recommendation is that PrintWriter swallows exceptions. So for example it shouldn't be used over a network. BufferedWriter is a better recommendation.